# Concurrent users using a DLL to access ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, web-service

So currently I have some ASP.net code where users are updated GIS through a DLL file that uses ArcObjects to talk to the MapService and layer.

My question is, will there be concurrent user issues? What if 10 people are submitting updates to the same items that need updating in ArcGIS map service? Will the DLL freeze up? Will ArcGIS service freeze up?

Or does it handle concurrent users in a Queue-style via the ArcGIS service, the DLL, or IIS itself maybe realizes the DLL is in use?

Comment: Is this a [server object extension](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000000zv000000)?

Comment: @blah238 I believe so. I setup web services in /rest/services, and use ArcObjects to store to the database based on an mxd map service file.